# why does my output generate random value?

Tags: c, input

The task of this code is to ask users for input, if user entered 6 integers then program move on, else it removes non-numeric value such as spaces, tabs or letters and ask user to make up the missing numbers.

The problem with my code is it always generate some random value.
For testing purpose I just print out what I have in array answer after the second input.

Case 1:

```
First input:1234
First output: You need to enter 2 more digits to complete your guess
Second input:56
Second output:1 2 5 6 -38 -48 (it is supposed to be 1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Case 2:

```
First input:12
First output: You need to enter 4 more digits to complete your guess
Second input:3456
Second output:1 2 0 0 3 4 (It is supposed to be 1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    int answer[6];

    char copy[100];
    int count = 0;
    fgets(copy, sizeof(copy), stdin);

    // Take inputs first time
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (isspace(copy[i])) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        if (!isdigit(copy[i])) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }

        answer[i] = copy[i] - '0';
    }

    if (count != 0) {
        printf("You need to enter %d more digits to complete your guess\n", count);
        fgets(copy, sizeof(copy), stdin);
        // Loop through the second input and add it to the answer array
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            answer[i + count] = copy[i] - '0';
        }
    }
    // Print the contents of the answer array
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d ", answer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if (count != 0)` be `if (count != 6)`?

Comment: Shouldn't you increment `count` when they enter a digit, not when they enter a non-digit?

Comment: my count means if there is a non-digit detected it increases, so i know i should take count amounts of new input

Comment: If they enter `123456` you won't increment `count` but they've entered 6 digits.

Comment: I just updated my qustion can you please check again, input and output are now changes

Comment: Why do you need the first `if` statement? Space isn't a digit, so `if (!isdigit(copy[j]))` will skip spaces.

Comment: The loops should stop when you get to the newline character. Otherwise you access uninitialized array elements when `j` or `p` is beyond the end of the input.

Comment: It might be easier to use `strtok` to break up the input string than to try it yourself. Another way might be say `int conv = sscanf(copy, "%d%d%d%d%d%d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4], &arr[5]);` to determine how many intgers were present.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think they want space-separated numbers, just individual digits.

Comment: If you enter `123 56`, than your `answer` is `123(undefined)56`. And since your `count` means how many characters that aren't digits, you should use `answer[j - count] = copy[j] - '0';`.

Comment: You can remove the `question` and `history` variable since they aren't used. And you can just use `i` and `copy` instead of `i`, `j`, `p`, `copy`, `copy2`.

Comment: "PLEASE HELP" is slightly rude, don't use uppercase that way here. SO is full of very kind people, don't worry they'll help you as much as they can.

Comment: @EasonHao, the program will _actually_ stuck if you change `answer[count] = copy[i] - '0';` to `answer[i + count] = copy[i] - '0';`.

Answer (score 1):

The code does the same thing twice, but not in the same way...

```
  // Take inputs first time
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (isspace(copy[j])) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        if (!isdigit(copy[j])) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }

        answer[j] = copy[j] - '0';
    }
```

and

```
    // Print error if needed
    char copy2[100];
    if (count != 0) {
        printf("You need to enter %d more digits to complete your guess\n", count);
        fgets(copy2, sizeof(copy2), stdin);
        // Loop through the second input and add it to the answer array
        for (int p = 0; p < 6; p++) {
            answer[p+count] = copy2[p] - '0';
        }
    }
```

are the same thing. Should not be repeated, but  also should not be different if repeated...

In the second `for` the code does not test for a digit. In the first part it test a bit more than needed... And both tests are wrong, or incomplete.

In any case a letter, that is not space or digit, would get into the vector...

> first generate 6 random integers, and then ask users for input, if user entered 6 integers then program move on, else it removes non-numeric value such as spaces, tabs or letters and ask user to make up the missing numbers.

Ok, but this is not in the code...

#### an example

Encapsulation is a simple way to go. Consider `Pack`, just as an example:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned total;
    unsigned remaining;
    unsigned answers[6];
} Pack;
```

So you can have

```
    int get_answers(Pack* asw);
    int show_pack(Pack*, const char*);
```

- `get_answers()` gets the address of such a `Pack` thing and fills in the answers
- `show_pack()` gets the address of a `Pack` and displays its contents

#### a complete example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned total;
    unsigned remaining;
    unsigned answers[6];
} Pack;

int get_answers(Pack* asw);
int show_pack(Pack*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    Pack one = {
        .answers   = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0},
        .total     = 6,
        .remaining = 6};

    int question[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        question[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;

    get_answers(&one);
    show_pack(&one, "Final answers: ");
    return 0;
}

int get_answers(Pack* asw)
{
    char line[100];
    while (asw->remaining > 0)
    {
        show_pack(asw,NULL);
        printf(
            "\n\nYou need to enter %u more digits to "
            "complete "
            "the %u-digits guess\n\tYour choices: ",
            asw->remaining, asw->total);
        char* p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        if (p == NULL) continue;
        while (*p != 0)
        {
            if (*p < '1')
            {
                ++p;
                continue;
            }
            if (*p > '9')
            {
                ++p;
                continue;
            };
            asw->answers[asw->total - asw->remaining] = (*p++ - '0');
            asw->remaining--;
            if (asw->remaining == 0) break; // outer loop
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int show_pack(Pack* pack, const char* msg)
{
    if (pack == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s",msg);
    printf(
        "%u/%u answers [ ", pack->total - pack->remaining, pack->total);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < pack->total - pack->remaining;
         i += 1)
        printf("  %u", pack->answers[i]);
    printf(
        " ]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### output

Note that

- in the example some answers are pre-loaded --- 1 2 and 3
- The program goes over any non-digit or zero
- the function prints the answers before reading
- `fgets` returns a pointer that must be used

if this is `p.exe`...

```
Stack Overflow >
Stack Overflow >
Stack Overflow > p
3/6 answers [   1  2  3 ]


You need to enter 3 more digits to complete the 6-digits guess
        Your choices: Stack Overflow0005
4/6 answers [   1  2  3  5 ]


You need to enter 2 more digits to complete the 6-digits guess
        Your choices: 6
5/6 answers [   1  2  3  5  6 ]


You need to enter 1 more digits to complete the 6-digits guess
        Your choices: 4
Final answers: 6/6 answers [   1  2  3  5  6  4 ]

Stack Overflow >
```

#### about the code

This is the important part

```
int get_answers(Pack* asw)
{
    char line[100];
    while (asw->remaining > 0)
    {
        show_pack(asw,NULL);
        printf(
            "\n\nYou need to enter %u more digits to "
            "complete "
            "the %u-digits guess\n\tYour choices: ",
            asw->remaining, asw->total);
        char* p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        if (p == NULL) continue;
        while (*p != 0)
        {
            if ((*p < '1') || (*p > '9'))
            {
                ++p;
                continue;
            }
            asw->answers[asw->total - asw->remaining] = (*p++ - '0');
            asw->remaining--;
            if (asw->remaining == 0) break; // outer loop
        } // while
    } // while
    return 0;
}
```

- A loop runs until no more remaining questions.
- A call to `fgets` gets a whole line
- An internal loop extracts the digits and fills in the array of answers
- `show_pack` at start of the loop shows the questions entered so far.

If there no preloaded answers and the user enters

```
0/6 answers [  ]


You need to enter 6 more digits to complete the 6-digits guess
        Your choices: 123
3/6 answers [   1  2  3 ]


You need to enter 3 more digits to complete the 6-digits guess
        Your choices: 4
4/6 answers [   1  2  3  4 ]


You need to enter 2 more digits to complete the 6-digits guess
        Your choices: 5
5/6 answers [   1  2  3  4  5 ]


You need to enter 1 more digits to complete the 6-digits guess
        Your choices: One is missing
5/6 answers [   1  2  3  4  5 ]


You need to enter 1 more digits to complete the 6-digits guess
        Your choices: 6
Final answers: 6/6 answers [   1  2  3  4  5  6 ]
```

You see the logic:

- at start there are no answers
- when there are no digits the program goes on
- when completed, see the use of the second parameter in `show_pack`

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

<sup>As pointed in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78064913/21957823),</sup> Your code does the similar thing twice, and there are some problems:

- Your second input doesn't test whether the input is a digit.
- If the user inputs `12 3`, then `answer` is `12(undefined)3`.
- Your code can only use the first 6 characters of the input.
- As @Barmar commented:

> The loops should stop when you get to the newline character. Otherwise you access uninitialized array elements when j or p is beyond the end of the input.

## Solution

To solve this problem, you can use something like a [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stack/info). Here's a basic example of stack:

```c
struct stack{
    int data[];
    int top;
}
```

To make easier to understand, you can use `answer` to store the result of the input, and `count` to store **how many digits input**, and that is exactly **the index of the next column to input in `answer`**. You can use `input` to store the inputs.

Declaration:

```c
int answer[6], count = 0;
char input[102];
```

A point is that you can't expect that the input is perfect, so you have to request for input until there are enough <sup>(in your example, 6)</sup> digits input. The code is `while (count < 6)` as `count` means how many digits input.

Every time before you request for input, you have to empty the input variable `input`.
Then, you request for input.
After that, you analysis `input`. You have to check every non-null-terminator character of `input` and input the digits to `answer` when aren't enough digits input.

Input example:

```c
while (count < 6)
{
    printf("Enter %d digits:\n", 6 - count);
    memset(input, '\0', sizeof(input));
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(input); i < len && count < 6; i++)
    {
        if ('0' <= input[i] && input[i] <= '9')
        {
            answer[count++] = input[i] - '0';
        }
    }
}
```

### Implementation of different prompts

If you want some differences in the first and other prompts, you can use the [`static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static) register type keyword.
Change

```c
printf("Enter %d digits:\n", 6 - count);
```

to

```c
static int firstRequest = 1;
if (firstRequest == 1)
{
    printf("Enter %d digits:\n", 6 - count);
    firstRequest = 0;
}
else if (firstRequest==0)
    printf("Enter more %d digits:\n", 6 - count);
```

## Full example

A full example <sup>(with no differences in prompts)</sup> :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int answer[6], count = 0;
    char input[102];

    // input
    while (count < 6)
    {
        printf("Enter %d digits:\n", 6 - count);
        memset(input, '\0', sizeof(input));
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        for (int i = 0, len = strlen(input); i < len && count < 6; i++)
        {
            if ('0' <= input[i] && input[i] <= '9')
            {
                answer[count++] = input[i] - '0';
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the contents of the answer array
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", answer[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Enter 6 digits:
12
Enter 4 digits:
abc 5 6
Enter 2 digits:
 23
1 2 5 6 2 3
```